# Cannot run k run on helloweb demo app

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to launch web project with vNext with `k run`, but it doesn't work; when I put the localhost:port in my browser it doesn't give me any webpage!

I cloned https://github.com/aspnet/Home/tree/master/samples/HelloWeb content (json and cs files) into a directory, ran a command prompt in this directory and executed:

```
kpm restore
k run
```

Now the Console it says

> Demo does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for any endpoint

So it looks like it worked, but if I go to the localhost:port that I have in json under "web", my browser shows an error page (not found).

How can I debug this?

`kvm list` shows me that 1.0.0-beta2 CLR x86 is set to active with default alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `k web`, not `k run`. The latter is for console applications.

As explained on [aspnet/Home on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/home):

> Run the sample using the appropriate K command:
>
> - For the console app run `k run`.
> - For the web apps run `k web` on Windows or `k kestrel` on Mono.